# Symfony Composer update

Tags: symfony

I've got this error:

> C:\wamp64\www\Symfony>php composer.phar self-update
>   Updating to version ded485d.
>   [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException] Too many
>   arguments, expected arguments "command" "version". self-update
>   [-r|--rollback] [--clean-backups] [--no-progress] [--update-keys]
>   [--stable] [--preview] [--snapshot] [--] []

Comment: Questions should be clear and asked in English!

Answer (score 2):

Normally you should run composer with the command `composer` and not using `php composer` or `composer.phar`. On Windows, you should create a batch file in the directory where you downloaded the phar file [as per the install instructions](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#manual-installation). So for example if you downloaded the phar to `C:\bin` you would use the following command line script to create the proper batch file:

```
C:\bin>echo @php "%~dp0composer.phar" %*>composer.bat
```

Then make sure you have the path `C:\bin` added to your Windows `PATH` environment variable.

From you question it seems that you want to do 1 of either 2 things, update Composer or update your Symfony project.

1. Update Composer. Just run:

   composer self-update
2. Update your Symfony project. Change to your Symfony project folder root and then run the update:

   cd C:\wamp64\www\Symfony
   composer update

Let me know if there are questions.

Comment: You should click the "checkmark" to indicate if my answer is correct, or click the "up" arrow if I helped! THank you!